# Dynamic Search Function Test Method on QueryString

Tags: apex, code-coverage, dynamic-soql

I am having a problem testing a queryString within a Dynamic Search function. For example, I have a list of strings related to Contact record. Within the VisualForce page, I run a Search Function to call the string elements and in my Class I add the queryString to the SOQL query. I am using the string `queryString += ' and AUD_Priority_Provider__c = true';` for checkbox being true and `queryString += ' and firstName LIKE \'%'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(firstName)+'%\' ';` for text fields. (I have re-purposed code from Jeff Douglas for the Dynamic Search Function)

My Test Method currently results in 72% code coverage, however, my code to test the queryString function is not working.

In my Test Method I am creating the records, setting the Page Parameter, running the query on a checkbox and returning the results, however, as you will see in the code coverage, I am not able to call the queryString line item. Am I missing something in my Test Method to set and get the queryString?

Any direction you may be able to provide in testing the queryString function is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Here is my Class:

```
public class ADCampaignControllerExtension {

    public String size { get; set; } 

    private String queryString {get;set;}

    private final AD_Campaign__c ad;

    public Id AdCampaignId { get; set; }


    //This is Our collection of the class/wrapper objects WrapperContactWrapper 

    Public List<WrapperContactWrapper> wrapperlist; 

    Public Integer noOfRecords{get; set;} 


    // Create a new Map to verify whether the contact is already added in the Map 

    Map <id,Contact> SelectedcontactMap = new Map <id,Contact>(); 

    public boolean display{get;set;} 

    public list<Contact> selectedList {get;set;} 

    private ApexPages.StandardSetController standardSetController { get; set; }


    // The extension constructor initializes the private member
    // variable ad by using the getRecord method from the standard
    // controller.
    public ADCampaignControllerExtension(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.ad = (AD_Campaign__c)stdController.getRecord();

        initializeStandardSetController();

        //load records
        getContact();

    }

    // format queryString for display on the visualforce page
    //public String debugSoql {
    //get { return queryString; }
    //set;
    //}

    private Boolean isNullOrEmpty(String str) {
        if (str == null) return true;
        if (str.trim().length() == 0) return true;

        return false;
    }


    private void initializeStandardSetController() { 
            String aud = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('aud');
            String benzo = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('benzo');
            String pain = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('pain');
            String testosterone = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('testosterone');
            String insomnia = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('insomnia');
            String visn = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('visn');
            String sta3n = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('sta3n');
            String stationName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('stationName');
            String name = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('name');
            String firstName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('firstName');
            String lastName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('lastName');

            List<Profile> PROFILE = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Profile WHERE Id=:userinfo.getProfileId() LIMIT 1];
            String ProfileName = PROFILE[0].Name;

            queryString = 'SELECT Id, firstName, lastName, Name, account.name, account.visn__c, Sta3n__c, Station_Name__c, ProviderClass__c, Provider_Type__c, Title, Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c, AUD_Priority_Provider__c, Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c, Pain_Priority_Provider__c, Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c FROM contact WHERE name != null';

            if (aud == 'true')
            queryString += ' and AUD_Priority_Provider__c = true';

            if (benzo == 'true')
            queryString += ' and Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c = true';

            if (pain == 'true')
                queryString += ' and Pain_Priority_Provider__c = true';

            if (testosterone == 'true')
                queryString += ' and Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c = true';

            if (insomnia == 'true')
                queryString += ' and Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c = true';

            if (ProfileName == 'V21 Group') {
                    queryString += ' and account.visn__c = 21';
                } else if (ProfileName == 'V22 Group') {
                    queryString += ' and account.visn__c = 22';
                } else if (!isNullOrEmpty(visn)) {
                   queryString += ' and account.visn__c = '+visn+'';
                } 

            if (!isNullOrEmpty(sta3n))
                queryString += ' and sta3n__c LIKE \'%'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(sta3n)+'%\'';

            if (!isNullOrEmpty(stationName))
                queryString += ' and station_name__c LIKE \'%'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(stationName)+'%\'';            

            if (!isNullOrEmpty(name))
                queryString += ' and name LIKE \'%'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(name)+'%\''; 

            if (!isNullOrEmpty(firstName))
                queryString += ' and firstName LIKE \'%'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(firstName)+'%\''; 

            if (!isNullOrEmpty(lastName))
                queryString += ' and lastName LIKE \'%'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(lastName)+'%\''; 

            queryString += ' ORDER BY name LIMIT 2000';

            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));

            // sets the number of records in each page set
            setCon.setpagesize(15); 
            noOfRecords = setCon.getResultSize(); 

    }

    // instantiate the StandardSetController from a query locator 
    public ApexPages.StandardSetController setCon { 
        get { if(setCon == Null) {                    
            setCon = new ApexPages.StandardSetController(Database.getQueryLocator(queryString));
            }      
            return setCon; 
                } 
            set; 
    } 


    //Returns a list of wrapper objects for the sObjects in the current page set 
    Public List<WrapperContactWrapper> getContact() { getSelectedContact(); 

    // Initilaize the list to add the selected contact 
    wrapperlist = new List <WrapperContactWrapper>(); 
        for(Contact cc : (List<contact>)setCon.getRecords()) { 

            if( SelectedcontactMap .ContainsKey(cc.id)) { 

                wrapperlist.add (new WrapperContactWrapper(cc,true)); 
            } else { wrapperlist.add(new WrapperContactWrapper(cc,false)); }  
        } return wrapperlist;
    } 

    public void getSelectedContact() { 
        if(wrapperlist!=null) { 
            for(WrapperContactWrapper wr:wrapperlist) { 
                if(wr.bool == true) { 
                // Add the selected contact id in to the SelectedcontactMap. 
                SelectedcontactMap.put(wr.con.id,wr.con); 

                // If you uncheck the contact, remove it from the selectedcontactMap
                } else { SelectedcontactMap.remove(wr.con.id); 

                        } 
            } 
        } 
    }


    // runs the search with parameters passed via Javascript
    public PageReference runSearch() {
        initializeStandardSetController();
        getContact();
        return null;
    }


    public void clickMe() { 
        display = true; 
        getSelectedContact(); 
        selectedList = SelectedcontactMap.values(); 
    } 


    public PageReference processSelected() {

         List<Participant__c> newParticipants = new List<Participant__c>();   
            // loop through a map using keyset function
             for(ID cid: SelectedcontactMap.keyset() ) {    
                 newParticipants.add(new Participant__c(Academic_Detailing_Campaign__c = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id'), contact__c = cid));
             }
             PageReference p;

             if(newParticipants.size() > 0) {

                 try {
                 Database.insert(newParticipants);
                 p = new ApexPages.StandardController(new AD_Campaign__c(id = AdCampaignId)).view();
                 } catch (System.DMLException e) {
                 ApexPages.addMessages(e);
                 }           
             }       
         return p;
    }


    public integer pageNumber { 
        get { return SetCon.getPageNumber(); 
        } 
        set; 
    } 

    Public class WrapperContactWrapper { 

    Public Contact con{get;set;} 
    Public boolean bool{get;set;} 

        public WrapperContactWrapper(Contact c,boolean bool) { 
            this.con = c; 
            this.bool = bool;
        } 

    } 

}
```

Here is my Test Method:

```
@IsTest 
public with sharing class ADCampaignControllerExtensionTest {
    @IsTest      
    public static void AdCampaignControllerTest() {

    ADCampaignControllerExtension controller = new AdCampaignControllerExtension(new ApexPages.StandardController(new AD_Campaign__c()));

    String queryString;

        // Create and insert an account
        Account acc = new Account(name='TestClient', visn__c = 21);
        insert acc;

        //Create and insert a contact
        Contact con = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestConFN', LastName = 'TestConLN', Email='test@testing.com', Title='Director', Sta3n__c = '691', Station_Name__c ='Palo Alto', ProviderClass__c ='Nurse', Provider_Type__c='Physician', Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c = true, Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c = true, Pain_Priority_Provider__c = true, Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c = true, AUD_Priority_Provider__c = false, AccountId=acc.Id); 
        insert con;

         //Create and insert a contact
        Contact con1 = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestConFN', LastName = 'TestConLN', Email='test@testing.com', Title='Director', Sta3n__c = '691', Station_Name__c ='Palo Alto', ProviderClass__c ='Nurse', Provider_Type__c='Physician', Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c = true, Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c = true, Pain_Priority_Provider__c = true, Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c = true, AUD_Priority_Provider__c = true, AccountId=acc.Id); 
        insert con1;

         //Create and insert a contact
        Contact con2 = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestConFN', LastName = 'TestConLN', Email='test@testing.com', Title='Director', Sta3n__c = '691', Station_Name__c ='Palo Alto', ProviderClass__c ='Nurse', Provider_Type__c='Physician', Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c = true, Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c = true, Pain_Priority_Provider__c = true, Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c = true, AUD_Priority_Provider__c = true, AccountId=acc.Id); 
        insert con2;

        //Create and insert a Campaign
        AD_Campaign__c adcam = new AD_Campaign__c(Campaign_Name__c='TestCampaign');
        insert adcam;

        //Create and insert an Outreach Visit
        Participant__c part = new Participant__c 
                (Academic_Detailing_Campaign__c = adcam.Id, contact__c = con.Id);
        insert part;

        //Create and insert a Priority Provider
        Participant__c newParticipants = new Participant__c (Academic_Detailing_Campaign__c = adcam.Id, contact__c = con.Id);
        insert newParticipants;


        Controller.runSearch();
        System.assert(controller.runSearch() == null);

        Controller.clickMe();
        System.assert(controller.clickMe() == null);

        Controller.processSelected();
        System.assert(controller.processSelected() == null);


        PageReference pageRef = Page.AdCampaign;
        Test.setCurrentPage(pageRef); 


        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('aud', 'true');
        String aud = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('aud');
        System.assertEquals('true', aud);

        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('firstName', 'TestConFN');
        String firstName = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('firstName');
        System.assertEquals('TestConFN', firstName);

        if (aud == 'true')
            queryString += ' and AUD_Priority_Provider__c = true';
        queryString = 'SELECT Id, firstName, lastName, Name, account.name, account.visn__c, Sta3n__c, Station_Name__c, ProviderClass__c, Provider_Type__c, Title, Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c, AUD_Priority_Provider__c, Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c, Pain_Priority_Provider__c, Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c FROM contact WHERE name != null AND AUD_Priority_Provider__c = true';

        List <contact> selectedContact = [SELECT Id, firstName, lastName, Name, account.name, account.visn__c, Sta3n__c, Station_Name__c, ProviderClass__c, Provider_Type__c, Title, Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c, AUD_Priority_Provider__c, Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c, Pain_Priority_Provider__c, Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c FROM contact WHERE name != null AND AUD_Priority_Provider__c = true];

        // Verify
        System.assertEquals(true, selectedContact[0].AUD_Priority_Provider__c);
        System.assertEquals(selectedContact.size() !=0, true);     

    }

}
```

Here is my VisualForce Page:

```
<apex:page standardController="AD_Campaign__c" extensions="ADCampaignControllerExtension"  sidebar="false">

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function selectAllCheckboxes(obj,receivedInputID){
            var inputCheckBox = document.getElementsByTagName("input");                  
            for(var i=0; i<inputCheckBox.length; i++){          
                if(inputCheckBox[i].id.indexOf(receivedInputID)!=-1){                                     
                    inputCheckBox[i].checked = obj.checked;
                }
            }
        }
    </script>     

    <apex:form id="myform"> 
        <apex:pageBlock title="Search National Database" mode="edit" id="criteria">
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  function doSearch() {
                      searchServer(
                        document.getElementById("aud").checked,
                        document.getElementById("benzo").checked,
                        document.getElementById("pain").checked,
                        document.getElementById("testosterone").checked,
                        document.getElementById("insomnia").checked,
                        document.getElementById("visn").value,
                        document.getElementById("sta3n").value,
                        document.getElementById("stationName").value,
                        document.getElementById("name").value,
                        document.getElementById("firstName").value,
                        document.getElementById("lastName").value
                      );
                  }
            </script> 

            <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">         
                <apex:param name="aud" value="" />
                <apex:param name="benzo" value="" />
                <apex:param name="pain" value="" />
                <apex:param name="testosterone" value="" />       
                <apex:param name="insomnia" value="" />
                <apex:param name="visn" value="" />
                <apex:param name="sta3n" value="" />
                <apex:param name="stationName" value="" />
                <apex:param name="name" value="" />
                <apex:param name="firstName" value="" />
                <apex:param name="lastName" value="" />
            </apex:actionFunction>

            <table width="100%" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
              <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">AUD Prority Provider <input type="checkbox" id="aud" onclick="doSearch();" /></td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Benzo in Elderly Priority Provider <input type="checkbox" id="benzo" onclick="doSearch();" /></td>           
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Pain Priority Provider <input type="checkbox" id="pain" onclick="doSearch();" /></td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Testosterone Priority Provider <input type="checkbox" id="testosterone" onclick="doSearch();" /></td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Insomnia Priority Provider <input type="checkbox" id="insomnia" onclick="doSearch();" /></td> 
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="padding-bottom: 10px;" colspan="5"></td>          
              </tr>                
              <tr>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Name <input type="text" id="name" onkeyup="doSearch();"/></td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">First Name <input type="text" id="firstName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/></td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Last Name <input type="text" id="lastName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/></td>              
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">VISN <input type="text" id="visn" onkeyup="doSearch();"/></td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Sta3n <input type="text" id="sta3n" onkeyup="doSearch();"/></td>
                <td style="font-weight:bold;">Station Name <input type="text" id="stationName" onkeyup="doSearch();"/></td>           
              </tr>
            </table>

        </apex:pageBlock>

        <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="results">  

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Top"> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Process List" action="{!clickMe}" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

                <!-- In our table, we are displaying the Contact records --> 

                <apex:pageblocktable value="{!Contact}" var="cc"> 

                    <apex:column >
                        <apex:facet name="header">
                            <apex:inputCheckbox onclick="selectAllCheckboxes(this,'inputId')"/>
                        </apex:facet>
                        <!-- This is our selected Boolean property in our wrapper class -->
                        <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!cc.bool}" id="inputId"/>
                    </apex:column>

                    <!-- This is how we access the contact values within our Contact container/wrapper --> 
                    <apex:column value="{!cc.con.firstName}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cc.con.lastName}"/>

                    <apex:column value="{!cc.con.account.VISN__c}" /> 

                    <apex:column value="{!cc.con.Sta3n__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!cc.con.Station_Name__c}"/>

                    <apex:column value="{!cc.con.ProviderClass__c}"/>
                    <apex:column >
                    <apex:outputField value="{!cc.con.Provider_Type__c}" id="ProviderType" />  
                        <apex:facet name="header">Provider Type</apex:facet>
                    </apex:column>
                    <apex:column value="{!cc.con.title}"/>

                    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="ondblClick" showOnEdit="saveButton,cancelButton" hideOnEdit="editButton" /> 

                </apex:pageblocktable> 

            <apex:pageBlockButtons location="Bottom"> 
                <apex:commandButton value="First" action="{!Setcon.First}" reRender="myform" /> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Previous" action="{!Setcon.Previous}" reRender="myform" /> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Next" action="{!Setcon.Next}" reRender="myform" /> 
                <apex:commandButton value="Last" action="{!Setcon.Last}" reRender="myform" /> 
            </apex:pageBlockButtons> 

            <apex:outputText >Page Number {!pageNumber} </apex:outputText> 

        </apex:pageblock> 

        <apex:pageblock rendered="{!display}"> 

                <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                    <apex:commandButton value="Add Participants" action="{!processSelected}" />
                    <apex:commandButton action="{!Cancel}" value="Cancel"/>
                    <apex:pageMessages id="errors"/>
                </apex:pageBlockButtons>
            <apex:outputPanel >
                <apex:pageblocktable value="{!selectedList}" var="w" > 
                    <apex:column value="{!w.id}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!w.account.VISN__c}"/> 
                    <apex:column value="{!w.Sta3n__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!w.Station_Name__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!w.name}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!w.ProviderClass__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!w.Provider_Type__c}"/>
                    <apex:column value="{!w.Title}"/>

                </apex:pageblocktable> 
            </apex:outputPanel> 
        </apex:pageblock> 
    </apex:form> 

</apex:page>
```

Here is the result of my Test Script:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are initialize  `ADCampaignControllerExtension controller = new AdCampaignControllerExtension(new ApexPages.StandardController(new AD_Campaign__c()));`

this first and after setting value in page parameter. First set the value and then initialize . Because your constructor you are calling your private method.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @TusharSharma answer, you've inserted the same contact 3 times with the following code in your test class:

```
    //Create and insert a contact
    Contact con = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestConFN', LastName = 'TestConLN', Email='test@testing.com', Title='Director', Sta3n__c = '691', Station_Name__c ='Palo Alto', ProviderClass__c ='Nurse', Provider_Type__c='Physician', Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c = true, Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c = true, Pain_Priority_Provider__c = true, Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c = true, AUD_Priority_Provider__c = false, AccountId=acc.Id); 
    insert con;

     //Create and insert a contact
    Contact con1 = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestConFN', LastName = 'TestConLN', Email='test@testing.com', Title='Director', Sta3n__c = '691', Station_Name__c ='Palo Alto', ProviderClass__c ='Nurse', Provider_Type__c='Physician', Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c = true, Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c = true, Pain_Priority_Provider__c = true, Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c = true, AUD_Priority_Provider__c = true, AccountId=acc.Id); 
    insert con1;

     //Create and insert a contact
    Contact con2 = new Contact(FirstName = 'TestConFN', LastName = 'TestConLN', Email='test@testing.com', Title='Director', Sta3n__c = '691', Station_Name__c ='Palo Alto', ProviderClass__c ='Nurse', Provider_Type__c='Physician', Benzo_in_Elderly_Priority_Provider__c = true, Insomnia_Priority_Provider__c = true, Pain_Priority_Provider__c = true, Testosterone_Priority_Provider__c = true, AUD_Priority_Provider__c = true, AccountId=acc.Id); 
    insert con2;
```

You've used the same firstName, lastName and email address for each of them. That makes them duplicate contacts and is may be contributing to your coverage issues.